# Sending sensor data received via Bluetooth from ESP32 to Android phone, then forwarding it to Thingsboard cloud

Tags: android, bluetooth, thingsboard

Goal:

- Send Data from controller (ESP32 or STM32F10C6T8 ) to Android phone using Bluetooth
- Send the data received from an Android phone from the controller to Thingsboard Cloud

Questions:

- Is this possible with any existing app, if so which ones?
- What modifications if any must be done on the cloud or Android app to accommodate sending the data to the cloud (any cloud provider is fine, need not be Thingsboard)

I have downloaded a Bluetooth serial app on my phone and have a Thingsboard demo dashboard prepared, but need a way to connect data received on the Bluetooth app from the controller to send it to the cloud

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.